# Does setting linetype also set linecolor?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following GNUPlot code:

```
greyLt      = 99
set linetype greyLt     lc rgb "#a1a1a1"
```

I discovered quite by accident that I can later use:

```
plot datafile using 0:(0) notitle with lines lc greyLt
```

Note that `**linecolor** greyLt` (99) plots correctly.  The terminal is `x11`.

May I safely rely on this behavior?  I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the documentation.  Having said that, I haven't found the hypertext documentation for GNUPlot 5, only a pdf, which makes searching more challenging.

```
gnuplot --version
gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gnuplot linetypes have pre-defined colors, but can be redefined by the user. To see the current linetype definitions including color, width, dash pattern, etc, use

```
show linetypes
```

When you issue a command like `plot datafile with lines lc 99` it is interpreted as "plot using the properties of the current linetype (linetype 1 in this case since it is the first and only line plotted) but use the color from linetype 99".

This is different from `plot datafile with lines lt 99`, which would use *all* the properties from linetype 99 including color but also included linewidth and dash pattern.

Comment: So the answer to the question "May I safely rely on this behavior?" is yes?  The explanation makes sense.